テキストファイルを読み込み改行ごとにリストに格納したい
下記を入力値として作成したアルゴリズムを実行していましたが、テキストファイルで入力値を読み込むことになりました。
N, K = map(int, input().split())
A = list(map(int, input().split()))
B = list(map(int, input().split()))

テキストファイルの例は以下です。
3 4
1 2 6 8 33 5 21 5 19 8
3 4 9 71 4 5 82 4 2 21

１段落目はN,Kに相当する２つの数字があり、２段落目と３段落目はAとBに相当する数字があります。各段落間は改行が入ってます。
このテキストファイルを読み込みN,K,A,Bに格納する方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

テキストファイルを data.txt として読み込むサンプルです。
with open('data.txt') as fo:
    lines = fo.read().splitlines()
    N, K = map(int, lines[0].split())
    A = list(map(int, lines[1].split()))
    B = list(map(int, lines[2].split()))

